# VirtualBox doesn't have enough space left on Device

Tags: linux, memory, windows-7, virtualbox, linux-mint

I have a problem on Oracle VirtualBox : it regularly tells me that I don't have enough space left on device, when updating or installing.

In the VB settings, I have set my Motherboard base memory at 3370MB.
My HD IDE Primary Master has an actual size of 2MB and virtual size of 20GB, and my Optical Drive IDE Secondary Master is 1,46GB.
The Linux distribution is 1.534G.

When I run df -h in the VB, it tells me that the full filesystems are :

- /dev/sr0, 1.5G, mounted on /cdrom
- /dev/loop0, 1.5G, mounted on /rofs
- /cow, 1.7G and 72k available, mounted on /

I am running it from a Windows 7, and the distribution I use inside the box is the latest Linux Mint.

I don't know if this is the relevant information you need, please ask me if you need anything else.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Drive space <> memory. If you're getting a *not enough memory* error from VirtualBox itself, it means you don't have enough RAM.

Comment: The latest I got is a 'no space left on device' from Linux console. I don't think it's a RAM problem because it only occurs after updates or downloads.

Comment: Then that's not *virtualbox doesn't have enough memory*, is it? *No space left on device* is not the same thing. Again, **drive space <> memory**. It helps if you provide the actual details instead of paraphrasing, especially when that paraphrasing is 100% incorrect. Your *72K available*  on /cow is incredibly low. It appears you need to free up some disk space or move VirtualBox to a different volume.

Comment: Probably best to install Mint  to the hard disk rather than running the live CD version, unless you need that for some reason.

Comment: I have 764 GB available on my windows machine. I also can't install Linux directly on the drive, I have to use a virtual machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. The problem is that if you don't install Mint inside of the virtual machine, the only space available is your memory, so it is used as drive space. The solution was to first boot it via the live CD version, then install it inside of the virtual machine, and then reboot it using the version of Mint you just installed on the virtual hard disk you have in the virtual machine.